# Using a scope within an association in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Apologies if my title is a bit non-specific, not sure how to phrase this question without example code.

Here goes:

### Models:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base 
   has_one :gallery
end

class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :images
   scope :processed_images, -> { joins(:images).on('image.image_processing = false')
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image
  store_in_background :image
end
```

I want to get the processed images only, through the association, something like:

```
profile.gallery.processed_images
```

EDIT: or maybe

```
profile.gallery.images.processed
```

or in sql:

```
select * from images where image.gallery_id = ? and image.image_processing = false
```

Can I go through the profile.gallery association or do I have to do something like

```
Image.where('gallery_id = ? and image_processing = false', gallery_id)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION 1:**

change the scope definition to

```
has_many :processed_images, -> { where(image_processing: false) }, class_name: 'Image'
```

bear in mind that `scope` is used to filter the current class so defining a scope in the gallery model will mean that you want to filter the galleries table.

Then just call `profile.gallery.processed_images`

**SOLUTION 2:**

Move the scope in the gallery model to the image model

```
scope :processed, -> { where(image_processing: false) }
```

and then just call `profile.gallery.images.processed`

Comment: `image_processing` is in the `Image` model not the gallery.

Comment: that is right.  look at the examples in the api http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many

Comment: Thanks, you are right - place the scope on the Image model, of course! Didn't know about solution 1 - that's very cool :)